# How to format a number to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, math, numbers

I'm working with Stripe Checkout, and feed the amount as a number like so `11999`. How can I show this number as a string like `$119.99`?

I tried `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { currency: 'USD' }).format(11999)`

But it's show as `$ 11,999`

I tried http://numeraljs.com as well, but same issue. Any one have an idea?

Comment: What's the problem with the current format?

Comment: but how can it add decimal to your number?

Comment: `.format(11999 / 100)` by converting cents to dollars first?

Comment: the input is problematic. 11999 is 11 thousand 999 hundred

Comment: Thanks @adiga. I feel stupid for not thinking of that.

Comment: in english format, "," separates the thousands, the formatting is then correct. The function cannot know that for you "11999" means "119.99". You have to enter specifically "119.99" or divide by 100

Comment: You need to add the decimal point to the number 119.99 because now it take it as a number  without decimal part

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, change the cents to dollars by dividing by 100 (the number of cents in a dollar). Then prepend the `$`.

```js
const num = 11999;
const res = "$" + (num / 100);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in couple of ways.

First way is to parse it as a number and than divide it by 100 but that has a downside if your number has more than 2 decimal numbers.

```
let format = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
});

format.format(parseFloat(11999)/100);
```

If your number has more decimal points you can do something like:

```
let numberOfDigits = 2;
format.format(parseFloat(11999)/numberOfDigits*10);
```